# Haskell : Will GHC optimize this?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Can GHC simplify `id = (\(a, b) -> (a, b)).(\(a, b) -> (a, b))` into `id = \(a, b) -> (a, b)`?

What about more complicated case :

```
id (Just x) = Just x
id Nothing = Nothing

map f (Just x) = Just (f x)
map _ Nothing  = Nothing
```

Will GHC simplify `id . map` into `map`?

I tried to use plain beta reduction but it looks like these terms are irreducible because of the nasty pattern matching.

Therefore I am curious how do GHC's optimization techniques deal with that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can ask these questions of ghc by running it with [`-ddump-simpl`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/debugging.html). This will cause ghc to dump the "core" code that it compiles programs into. Core is an intermediate language between the part of the compiler that reasons about Haskell code and the part of the compiler that transforms that code into machine code.

When I compiled the following with `-O2 -ddump-simpl` the results surprised me.

```
tupid1 :: (a, b) -> (a, b)
tupid1 = (\(a, b) -> (a, b))

tupid2 :: (a, b) -> (a, b)
tupid2 = (\(a, b) -> (a, b)) . (\(a, b) -> (a, b))
```

The resulting core for `tupid1` makes a new specialized identity function.

```
-- RHS size: {terms: 4, types: 7, coercions: 0}
tupid1 :: forall a_aqo b_aqp. (a_aqo, b_aqp) -> (a_aqo, b_aqp)
[GblId,
 Arity=1,
 Caf=NoCafRefs,
 Str=DmdType <S,1*U(U,U)>m,
 Unf=Unf{Src=InlineStable, TopLvl=True, Value=True, ConLike=True,
         WorkFree=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(arity=1,unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=True)
         Tmpl= \ (@ a_ayd)
                 (@ b_aye)
                 (ds_dIl [Occ=Once] :: (a_ayd, b_aye)) ->
                 ds_dIl}]
tupid1 = \ (@ a_ayd) (@ b_aye) (ds_dIl :: (a_ayd, b_aye)) -> ds_dIl
```

In core the polymorphic type arguments to functions are represented as explicit arguments. `tupid1` takes two of these type arguments, named `a_ayd` and `b_aye`, for the two type variables `a` and `b` in its signature. It also takes a term `ds_dIl` that has the type of a tuple of those two types (`ds_dIl :: (a_ayd, b_aye)`) and returns it unmodified.

The surprising result is `tupid2` ...

```
-- RHS size: {terms: 1, types: 0, coercions: 0}
tupid2 :: forall a_aqm b_aqn. (a_aqm, b_aqn) -> (a_aqm, b_aqn)
[GblId,
 Arity=1,
 Caf=NoCafRefs,
 Str=DmdType <S,1*U(U,U)>m,
 Unf=Unf{Src=InlineStable, TopLvl=True, Value=True, ConLike=True,
         WorkFree=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(arity=1,unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=True)
         Tmpl= \ (@ a_axZ) (@ b_ay0) (x_aIw [Occ=Once] :: (a_axZ, b_ay0)) ->
                 x_aIw}]
tupid2 = tupid1
```

... which ghc simplifies to `tupid1`! How it deduces that is beyond my immediate knowledge or ability to discover.

---

The identity example for `Maybe`

```
maybeid :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
maybeid (Just x) = Just x
maybeid Nothing = Nothing
```

Is also simplified to an identity function with no pattern matching

```
-- RHS size: {terms: 3, types: 4, coercions: 0}
maybeid :: forall a_aqn. Maybe a_aqn -> Maybe a_aqn
[GblId,
 Arity=1,
 Caf=NoCafRefs,
 Str=DmdType <S,1*U>,
 Unf=Unf{Src=InlineStable, TopLvl=True, Value=True, ConLike=True,
         WorkFree=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(arity=1,unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=True)
         Tmpl= \ (@ a_aqI) (ds_dIq [Occ=Once] :: Maybe a_aqI) -> ds_dIq}]
maybeid = \ (@ a_aqI) (ds_dIq :: Maybe a_aqI) -> ds_dIq
```

The core for `map` for `Maybe` isn't interesting for this question

```
maybemap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
maybemap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
maybemap _ Nothing = Nothing
```

But if it's composed with `maybeid`

```
maybeidmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
maybeidmap f = maybeid . maybemap f
```

ghc simplifies it to `maybemap`

```
-- RHS size: {terms: 1, types: 0, coercions: 0}
maybeidmap
  :: forall a_aqp b_aqq.
     (a_aqp -> b_aqq) -> Maybe a_aqp -> Maybe b_aqq
[GblId,
 Arity=2,
 Caf=NoCafRefs,
 Str=DmdType <L,1*C1(U)><S,1*U>,
 Unf=Unf{Src=InlineStable, TopLvl=True, Value=True, ConLike=True,
         WorkFree=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(arity=0,unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=True)
         Tmpl= maybemap}]
maybeidmap = maybemap
```

And it does the same thing if `id` is composed with `f`.

```
maybemapid :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
maybemapid f = maybemap (id . f)
```

The composition with the identity function is removed and the whole function simplifies to `maybemap`

```
-- RHS size: {terms: 1, types: 0, coercions: 0}
maybemapid
  :: forall a_aqq b_aqr.
     (a_aqq -> b_aqr) -> Maybe a_aqq -> Maybe b_aqr
[GblId,
 Arity=2,
 Caf=NoCafRefs,
 Str=DmdType <L,1*C1(U)><S,1*U>,
 Unf=Unf{Src=InlineStable, TopLvl=True, Value=True, ConLike=True,
         WorkFree=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(arity=2,unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=False)
         Tmpl= \ (@ a_ar2)
                 (@ b_ar3)
                 (f_aqL [Occ=Once!] :: a_ar2 -> b_ar3)
                 (eta_B1 [Occ=Once!] :: Maybe a_ar2) ->
                 case eta_B1 of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                   Nothing -> GHC.Base.Nothing @ b_ar3;
                   Just x_aqJ [Occ=Once] -> GHC.Base.Just @ b_ar3 (f_aqL x_aqJ)
                 }}]
maybemapid = maybemap
```